# Rails routing spec with mounted Sinatra application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm mounting a Sinatra-based gem into my application and would like to add a routing spec that verifies that the Sinatra app is indeed mounted at the correct path.

The main application should not contain any tests that are specific to the functionality of the gem because those are of course tested there.

Looking at the [RSpec routing matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/routing-specs) and the [Rails routing assertions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html), it seems they're only capable of dealing with controllers.

For now I have added a spec that just tests a POST request with `be_routable` but that's not really usable for all the routes because there's always danger of accidentally using some fallback route of the main application.

Comment: This is outside the scope of what routing specs are used for. Routing specs really just test that there is a route in the route collection. For this I would use a simple feature or request spec and actually hit the path with a http request. I rarely actually use routing specs however as that part of the application is covered by feature or request specs.

Comment: The problem is that the app in question expects fairly complex SOAP XML as input. I'd rather not have to update the specs of the main application everytime something in the gem changes or duplicate those request XMLs that are already thoroughly tested inside the gem.